# How to print double value in DecimalFormat

Tags: decimalformat

I have a code.

```
Double value = 6.589715E7;
DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY);
symbol.setGroupingSeparator(',');
final DecimalFormat doris = new DecimalFormat("#,###000",symbol );
System.out.println(changedValue);
```

which displays the value like this rite now.

65,897150

is there any way out this can be displayed as.

65,9 (also rounding off to one decimal place)

Comment: Why do you set a German locale which uses comma as the decimal point and then set the grouping separator to comma as well?  Combined with the weird pattern that only has the group separator for millions, but not for thousands, this gets really confusing. If you want to round to millions, you should probably just divide by one million.

Answer (score 0):

This example rounds up 2 but you get the point, try this 
inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 2);

Comment: That won't do much for 65,897,150 as that number has no fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

Here I put answer in string format. you can also convert into double format.

```
    Double value = 6.589715E7;
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbol = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY);
    symbol.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    final DecimalFormat doris = new DecimalFormat("##,###000",symbol );
    String str = String.valueOf(doris.format(value));
    String formated=str.replace(".", ",").substring(0,str.indexOf(",")+2);
    Log.e("Log","d result="+formated);
```

Comment: Why do you call `String.valueOf` on another String?

Comment: And this rounds to "65,8" not "65,9" as requested.